# Why isn't this switch case firing?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I have a whole line of switch cases tied to oncheckboxclickeds that I'm using to total up a number.

Every case in the line works beautifully, except the last one, which seems not to do anything at ALL, and I can't figure out why.

This works just fine, right till the end:

```
package com.example.blazingboltcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {



int attack=11;
int damage=3;
int flankAttack;
int pbs;
int justice;
int destruction;
int bane;
int DF;
int GMW;
int heroism;
int deadly;
int attackTotal;
int damageTotal;

String flames="";
String baneDice="";
String keen="";
String diceTotal;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}




public void onCheckboxClicked(View v) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();


    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.checkBox1:
        if (checked)
                {
                flankAttack=2;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }

        else
                {
                flankAttack=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
        break;

    case R.id.checkBox2:
        if (checked)
                {
                pbs=1; 
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
        else
                {
                pbs=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
        break;

    case R.id.checkBox3:
            if (checked)
            {
                justice=2;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
               }
            else
            {
                justice=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox4:
            if (checked)
            {
                destruction=4;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
            else
            {
                destruction=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox5:
            if (checked)
            {
                bane=2;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;
                baneDice="+2d6";
                diceTotal="1d8"+baneDice+flames+keen;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                textView3.setText(diceTotal);
                }
            else
            {
                bane=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;
                baneDice="";
                diceTotal="1d8"+baneDice+flames+keen;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                textView3.setText(diceTotal);
                }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox6:
            if (checked)
            {
                DF=3;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
            else
            {
                DF=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox7:
            if (checked)
            {
                flames="+1d6 fire";
                diceTotal="1d8"+baneDice+flames+keen;
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                textView3.setText(diceTotal);
            }
            else
            {
                flames="";
                diceTotal="1d8"+baneDice+flames+keen;
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                textView3.setText(diceTotal);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox8:
            if (checked)
            {
                GMW=1;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
            else
            {
                GMW=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox9:
            if (checked)
            {
                heroism=2;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
               }
            else
            {
                heroism=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
                }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox10:
            if (checked)
            {
                keen="+19-20 crit";
                diceTotal="1d8"+baneDice+flames+keen;
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                textView3.setText(diceTotal);
            }
            else
            {
                keen="";
                diceTotal="1d8"+baneDice+flames+keen;
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                textView3.setText(diceTotal);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox11:
            if (checked)
            {
                deadly=2;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
            }
            else
            {
                deadly=0;
                attackTotal=attack+flankAttack+pbs+justice+bane+DF+GMW+heroism+deadly;
                damageTotal=damage+pbs+destruction+bane+DF+GMW+deadly;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(attackTotal));
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(damageTotal));
            }
    }
}
```

}

I'm kinda new to programming, does anyone have any idea what might be gumming up the works? The whole mess works perfectly aside from that very last Case.

Comment: Try logging R.id.checkBox11 and the variable you are switching over to make sure that they are the same at some point.  I don't know what else to tell you without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Check the value of each `R.id.checkBox*` in case `R.id.checkBox11` is a duplicate of an earlier one. I doubt it, but it's just a sanity check.

Comment: After a little bit of research, I'f found that I have absolutely no idea how to log R.id.checkBox11 or the variable. Or really how to log at all. Sorry to be a burden guys, I just started programming on friday, but thanks for the help!

Comment: `Log.d("TAG", "A String");` replace the second parameter with any string that you want to send to the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we would need a bit more information to help you. However, I assume you are trying to use the [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) which is implemented by your main Activity? If you are having trouble with referencing IDs, you can always just implement an individual lisenter on a specific element, for example:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
   {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( isChecked )
            {

                prevChecked = true;
        Log.d("CHECKBOX","Previously Checked = "+prevChecked);
            }else{

                prevChecked = false;
        Log.d("CHECKBOX","Previously Checked = "+prevChecked);

            }

        }
    });
```

Where prevChecked is a global variable. I have also thrown in a couple of Log's so you can output the information to the LogCat. Hope that helps in your debugging.

******* EDIT TO SUIT YOUR ADDED COMMENT *************************

Have you tried to swap your switch statement with and if statement. e.g.

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.checkbox1){

}else if(v.getId() == R.id.checkbox2){

}
```

Additionally, what interface is `onCheckboxClicked(View v)`, is this a custom element? How have you defined your check boxes in your R.layout.activity_main.xml? If you have a checkbox interface you need to implement a listener like my example above. I can't see that your setting a listener anywhere, nor are you implementing it in your activity. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onCheckChangedListener {
```

But as far as I can tell, unless it is a custom element it doesn't make any sense that `public void onCheckboxClicked(View v)` Even get's called. This [example](http://vimaltuts.com/androids/android-checkbox-example) might help.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'll edit the post with the whole code, since I wasn't trying to use OnCheckedChangeListener, and I think including the full thing might make more sense.

Comment: I saw several other folks using onCheckboxClicked(View v) to try to make this type of program here on stack overflow. I'm sure there's probably a better way to do it than what I've been doing, but I haven't come upon it yet.